# Correct syntax to parse JSONP response from Facebook Open Graph

Tags: jquery, json, facebook, jsonp, facebook-opengraph

I'm using one call to the Facebook Open Graph API to grab two sets of JSONP data, and having some trouble parsing the response.

Here's my code:

```
// The IDs to the fan pages to like
var likeURLs = ['71671905072','146175949904'];
// The base of the URL we will build to query the API
var reqURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=";
// Construct the rest of reqURL using our fan pages
for (var i=0; i < likeURLs.length; i++) {
    reqURL += likeURLs[i];
    if (i != (likeURLs.length - 1)) {reqURL += ',';} else {reqURL += "&callback=?"}
};

function getLikes(){
    $.getJSON(reqURL, function(data){
        console.dir(data);
    });
}

getLikes();
```

The data is successfully returned, but I'm spacing on how to access it correctly.  For whatever reason, `data[0]` won't work, nor will `data.71671905072`.  Can anybody point me towards the right syntax?  It's late and my brain is not working very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data["71671905072"]` should work.

Comment: Duh.  You got it.  Thanks for the tip :)